# @media overwrites main style even outside the breakpoint

Tags: css

I have 3 `.footer-div`s inside a `flex` wrapper and they have this simple style, nothing else (no prefixes he in order to be concise):

```
.footer-flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}    

.footer-div {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: anything) {
  .footer-flex-wrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }  

  .footer-div {
    flex-basis: 90%;
  }    
}
```

I am using Brackets as editor and the above style is the only thing I am doing with the `.footer-div`s and their wrapper. 
I found out that the style below is overwriting the one on top even outside the media query, which for me is really strange. I cannot figure out why this happens.

Any help is most welcome! :)

Sorry for keeping this question abstract but it really is a very simple flex wrapper with 3 divs inside and the whole style is what you see above.

IMPORTANT: the styles of all other elements, even in the same media query, work perfectly and there is only one CSS sheet.

Comment: can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WwQggO

Comment: I try to find a way not to add too many elements and styles and simplify the fiddle. The codepen works and my code did work just a couple of days ago. I really think I did something wrong in the process and found out that the problem is the relationship of the main style and the media query.

Comment: Found the problem. A curly bracket too many in the middle of the code. It drove me crazy! ahahahhahahaha